# Modem config match

Tags: modem

I have two similar modems, when I insert the SIM in the first modem it connects automatically to the network. But if I insert the same SIM in the second modem, it doesn't connect to the network.

I launched the command: `AT&V` to read the profile of each modem. I compared the settings and they are all the same except for the following:

```
+CGDCONT: (1,"IP","cmnet","0.0.0.0",0,0)
+CGDCONT: (1,"IP","internet","0.0.0.0",0,0)
----------------------
+CIND: 0,3,1,0,0,0,1,0
+CIND: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
----------------------
+CGATT: 1
+CGATT: 0
----------------------
 +COPS: 1,0,""
 +COPS: 0,2,""
----------------------
```

Q1: Could one of these settings cause the problem?

Q2: Is there a way to save/restore a modem config?

NB. The first setting of each pair is of the working modem.

Comment: Use COPS to make a PLMN scan. Use CFUN to check if radio is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the APN of the second modem is different from the first one. The APN of second modem is "internet", while the first one is "cmnet". This can cause the problem (first one is attached while the second one did not: +CGATT 1 vs 0), if the network does not support "internet" APN.

You can set same APN for the second modem as the first one to have a try. i.e.

```
AT+CGDCONT =1,"IP","cmnet"
```

But, APN difference is only one of the possible reasons. For analyzing the actual reason of attach failure, logs are needed.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help, what Iwant is just connect to GSM network, to send SMS or check Balance.